# How to use distributed package in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have an issue when I try to execute the following code using python3.6, but it's working well on python2.7:

```py
from distributed.compatability import FileExistsError
try:
   os.mkdir(name)
   logging.info("dir created")
except FileExistsError:
   logging.info("dir already exists")

Error:
======
 from distributed.compatability import FileExistsError
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileExistsError'
```

I have installed the distributed package using conda, but still getting the same error. Did I miss anything? Can someone help me to make it work with python3.6?

Comment: What specific package is this? [`distributed`](https://pypi.org/project/distributed/) seems to be something completely different.

Comment: @Norrius that is the correct package, it just has most of the stuff removed from it due to dropped python 2 support.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import `FileExistError` from `distributed.compatibility`, remove this, because `FileExistError` is part of standard library.

```
import distributed.compatability
try:
   os.mkdir(name)
   logging.info("dir created")
except FileExistsError:
   logging.info("dir already exists")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @rozumir mentioned, `FileExistsError` was added in Python 3. So there was only a need to import it in Python 2.

If you look on their Github you can see that it was only added for compatibility reasons. Hence the name `distributed.compatibility`.

It was added on [this](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/0114e1c3031244bd647301cae65de391d10ec6d3/distributed/compatibility.py#L50) commit in October 2016, however in July 2019, [Python 2 support was dropped](https://github.com/dask/distributed/commit/157eada32c7c49c3f1b0fe9e020be74592ab27fd#diff-96e9d355df871db11ae609749a4b0fe04f5b106f6f61ab5d82ef8cdfb0115bd4), eliminating the need for much of the stuff in `distributed.compatibility`.

So in essence, in Python 3 versions such as Python 3.6, `FileExistsError` is just there and there is no need to import it to use it.